# Users asking how to uninstall my Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Some days ago the amount of users using my chrome extension raised from about 1.800 to 7.478 and now users are asking how to uninstall it and call it a virus.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pageliner/nepakmljodobhlbbkpobblnifmhclemh

Have you recognized any similar behaviour of users? They are all from russia...
I can uninstall it by simply right clicking and choosing "remove from chrome".

Comment: using google advanced search, i tried '"PageLiner" chrome extension, and for the region I chose Russia. [Here](http://forum.kasperskyclub.ru/index.php?showtopic=50673&page=1) was the only result. Looks like a forum for fixing a computer issue? Note the post is two days old

Comment: your extension may have shown up in this guy's browser/antivirus logs but didn't necessarily cause a problem. the translation is kinda rough so i'm not too sure

Answer (score 1):

*On uninstalling an extension*:

To remove an extension from Google Chrome:

1. On your browser, click menu .
2. Select More tools > Extensions.
3. On the extension you want to remove, click Remove from Chrome .
4. A notice to remove the extension will appear. Click Remove.

If an extension has an icon in your Chrome toolbar, you can right-click on the icon and select Remove from Chrome to uninstall the extension.

*On Removing possible malware*:

If the extension is still corrupted, it's possible that a suspicious program is changing this extension's files. In this case:

1. Run an antivirus or anti-malware software to remove any software programs that may be affecting Chrome. You can also try the [Software Removal Tool](https://www.google.com/chrome/cleanup-tool/).
2. Repair the extension.
3. If this doesn't work, visit the Chrome Help Forum and share your situation with us.

More about [managing chrome extensions here](https://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/answer/2664769?hl=en).